# I'm trying to access a SOAP endpoint. What does "unexpected encoding style" mean?

Tags: soap, clojure

I'm trying to write a clojure app to connect to a SOAP endpoint and download some data. I'm new to clojure and the project is somewhat ambitious for my skill level with the language. Part of the learning curve, I have discovered, is parsing the error messages that clojure produces. I have the following code:

```
(require '[clj-soap.core :as soap])
(defn -main
    "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
    [& args]
    (let [client (soap/client-fn "https://sna.etapestry.com/v2messaging/service?WSDL")]
    (client :login "username" "password") ;replaced with real credentials
    (client :logout))
(println "Hello, World!"))
```

Which produces this massive error message:

```
jonathan at tardis [11:47:19] ~/rc_import
[master]  ->  lein run                                                                      
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: caught exception while handling request: unexpected encoding style: expected=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/, actual=, compiling:(/tmp/form-init3897130533799964700.clj:1:72)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7142)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:307)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: caught exception while handling request: unexpected encoding style: expected=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/, actual=
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:555)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
    at clj_soap.core$client_call.doInvoke(core.clj:150)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:628)
    at clj_soap.core$client_proxy$iter__314__318$fn__319$soap_call__324.doInvoke(core.clj:156)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at clj_soap.core$client_fn$fn__335.doInvoke(core.clj:164)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:439)
    at rc_import.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:9)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:375)
    at user$eval5.invoke(form-init3897130533799964700.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6693)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    ... 11 more
```

The dependencies in my project.clj file are as follows:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
              [com.uswitch/clj-soap "0.2.3"]]
```

These are properly installed and the library is being imported correctly. The problem is the error message says

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: caught exception while handling request: unexpected encoding style: expected=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/, actual= ...
```

What does this mean? How do I fix it? I have no control at all over the endpoint xml file.

The really puzzling thing is that I can connect to the same endpoint just fine using python and suds. I'd continue with python, but I need the program to be cross platform and "idiot proof." The JVM is cross-platform, making it easier to port to Windows in particular than python would be, and I can write an "idiot resistant" program.

Comment: Are you sure you need the WSDL parameter to the URI? Typically you don't when you try to actually send a SOAP request.

Comment: Yes. I need the parameter, otherwise it resolves to an html page and not an xml page. Here's what you get without the WSDL parameter... https://sna.etapestry.com/v2messaging/service